# Storing/Accessing a simple variable in Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, local-storage, firefox-addon-sdk

I hope that I haven't missed an answer here to this question, which seems far too simple but I can't find an answer between Mozilla or Stackoverflow.

I am trying to use the Mozilla Addon SDK simple storage to store one single number that contains the number of pages that have been visited since the addon was activated. In order to do this I am increasing the variable number once on every page load. See code below. The only thing I can't find information on is how to load the stored data from the console (or, if I am misunderstanding, is this data not stored locally in the browser?). Where the comment says "//load ss.storage.page_visits" is where my problem arises - I cannot understand how to load this data.

```
var ss = require("sdk/simple-storage");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
//load ss.storage.page_visits
if (!ss.storage.page_visits){
    ss.storage.page_visits = 0;
}
var test=   '"<style>\
                h1{\
                    font-size: 5em;\
                    color: red;\
                    font-family: Helvetica;\
                }\
            </style>\
                <h1>test</h1><h2>' + ss.storage.page_visits + '</h2>"';

ss.storage.page_visits++;
if (ss.storage.page_visits/5 == 1){
    pageMod.PageMod({
      include: "*",
      contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' +
                     test
    });
    ss.storage.page_visits = 0;
}else{
    pageMod.PageMod({
      include: "*",
      contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' +
                     test
    });
}
console.log(ss.storage.page_visits);
```

Comment: There's no need to load it. You can simply access it. Your code should work as is. What does the console log?

Comment: Console doesn't have a log of the variable at all, and the variable included in the html text that should be counting up per page visit shows up as 0 no matter how many visits are made. I wish the code was working as is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with simple-storage. It's just that

> By default, cfx run and cfx test use a new profile each time they are executed. This means that any profile-specific data entered from one run of cfx will not, by default, be available in the next run.

See [Using `--profiledir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx#Using_--profiledir) to run on the same profile every time, or [Extension Auto-Installer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autoinstaller/) to run your extension without restarting the browser.

The way things are currently set up, your stored variable will increment once per install, not per page visit. If you want to increment it on page visit, you'll need to put `ss.storage.page_visits++` in the `PageMod`'s `onAttach` constructor function.

Also, why `ss.storage.page_visits/5 == 1`?

`ss.storage.page_visits == 5`

Comment: Aha, brilliant. Thank you, that is the puzzle piece I was missing. Had been wondering...

Comment: Also, the condition is because I had been testing a gradual count before where I wasn't resetting to 0; had just forgotten to edit it!